# What is this Asian dish made with boiled vegetables? 

Tags: vegetables, asian-cuisine, boiling

Does anyone know which is the dish where we have a pot/pan of boiling vegetables/meat in the center and people sit around it with their noodles and soup bowls and keep picking things from it and eating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean a hot-pot stew (*huǒ guō*). There are many styles, Wikipedia has a fairly good article about it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_pot

Answer (score 2):

In Japan they call it [nabe](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese%20nabe&hl=en&prmd=imvnse&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=6Z6CT66ID6njmAXr5_SHCA&ved=0CEsQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=929). Sometimes they add rice to it instead of noodles. As nico pointed out it is essentially a hot pot stew.